# Laravel 5.4 Listener on Session Timeout

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.4

I have done some research about this question, and most of them saying that it's impossible to do it. Is there any solution or hack way to do this? I just want to update the status of user in database if session timeout.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Take alook at this [thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-after-session-expired) it may help you ;)

Comment: @RomnickSusa I tried to do it inside unauthenticated() function inside App/Exceptions/Handler.php but I can't get the user id in this function as the session is timeout so i cant get the user id.

Comment: @Maraboc I read this thread before, this is only to redirect to a specific page, what i want is to get the user id and update the status inside database

Comment: it will do it if you replace `// function you want to fire when the user goes idle` with an ajax call to your controller to update your database

Comment: @Maraboc Ok, I will give it a try

Comment: the problem here if the user close the window in the navigator there is no other way to infor the controller in this case :p

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do it with a job:

For session use type database: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

there is a field called last_activity with a timestamp (I think laravel will update it automatically).

Now you can write a job that will detect all sessions that have a timestamp < last_activity + your_session_time and update the users.

Comment: I am using database to store session now, but when I logout, the user id inserted in database is null. So how can I detect this record belong to which user?

Comment: Each user generates a session, it does not matter if he is signed in or not. So if you want to track sessions from logged out users, you have to store the id in a separate field, so Laravel won't overwrite it. I would suggest after the user has logged in, you copy his user id in your own user_id-field in the session table.